# Prevent DIV from Wrapping with Fluid Layout

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I am having trouble preventing a DIV from wrapping to the next line when I shrink the browser window. There must be something small and simple I am missing, but I've been at it for a while now and I cannot figure it out.  It appears to only kick down the "blog" div, but not the "info" div.  Any suggestions?

Here is an example:
http://www.spynsycle.com/portfolio/

CSS:

```
/* Level 1 */
#container {
    min-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 768px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

/* Level 2 */
#portfolio {
    min-width: 396px;
    width: 40%;
    min-height: 768px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color:lightgreen;

} 
#information {
    min-width: 108px;
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 768px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: lightcoral;
}
#blog {
    min-width: 396px;
    width: 40%;
    min-height: 768px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Portfolio</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="portfolio">
                Port       
            </div>
            <div id="information">
                Info
            </div>
            <div id="blog">
                Blog
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're assigning `min-width` in pixels, as your page gets smaller, eventually you're running out of enough pixels to maintain the sum of your widths, and you browser is forcing your blog `div` to wrap. Your widths are totaling to `900px`, so once the browser window dips below `900px` you'll start seeing wrapping.

What's happening is eventually your `min-width` of `396px` becomes larger than `40%` of the browser width.

Comment: I actually had 300  for the two wider divs and 200 for the middle one initially, which did equal 800 pixels (my min width for the container), but naturally my basic math skills failed me, and I thought 300 was 40% of 800 and 200 was 20% of 800.  However, it is actually supposed to be 320 and 160.  
I knew it was something simple, thank you!

Comment: Yea, I can't count the number of times I've lost track of my width math, especially once padding and margin start getting involved.